# Mock case class in scala

Tags: scala, mocking, mockito

I have a trait

```
 trait Writer[T <: Attribute] {
  def read(boundingBox: BoundingBox): Future[List[T]]
}
```

and a case class

```
case class WriterImpl[T <: Attribute]()(implicit manifest: Manifest[T]) extends Writer[T] with LazyLogging {

override def read(boundingBox: BoundingBox): Future[List[T]] = {
}
..
}
```

In the Test class I want to mock the method read()

I tried this with exact values

```
  val writer = mock[WriterImpl[Attrib]]
        when(writer.read(new BoundingBox(41.90178412, 41.8798685, -87.62687021, -87.64884287)))
          .thenReturn(Future.successful(scala.collection.immutable.List(list)))

 verify(writer).read(new BoundingBox(41.90178412, 41.8798685, -87.62687021, -87.64884287))
```

also tried

```
val writer = mock[WriterImpl[Attrib]]
            when(writer.read(ArgumentMatchers.any()))
              .thenReturn(Future.successful(scala.collection.immutable.List(list)))
    
     verify(writer).read(ArgumentMatchers.any())
```

Instead of calling the mock method it calls the actual method

Comment: You didn't share how you use the mock. Please update your post.

Comment: Side note: your class makes more sense as a regular class rather than a case class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the first example, the problem is you use 2 different `BoundingBox` objects as parameters for the `read` method: one for `when` and another one for the `verify`. They will not match because at runtime they are different instances of the same `BoundingBox` class. You should use the same object. Store it before the `when` clause and then call `verify` passing that same object.

I assume you just removed the obvious call to `writer.read(...)` anywhere between the `when` and `verify` clauses. `verify` expects at least one call to `read`, otherwise it throws a `"Wanted but not invoked: writerImpl.read(...); Actually, there were zero interactions with this mock.."`

The second example should work, but you will still have the same issue if you'll try to check the result. You will result in 2 different instances of a `Future`: one in the `when` and another one in the `verify`. Since they are 2 different objects at runtime, they will not match:

```
result shouldBe Future.successful(scala.collection.immutable.List(new Attribute))
```

The output confirms the runtime sees 2 different instances:

```
Expected :Future(Success(List(org.scala.snippets.Test$Attribute@373052b5)))
Actual   :Future(Success(List(org.scala.snippets.Test$Attribute@17207f5b)))
```

Again, just store the `Future` before `when` and pass the same `Future` to both `when` and `shouldBe`. With these adjustments this should work. Checking the result of `read` confirms the same `Future` was returned from the call:

```
import Test.{Attribute, BoundingBox, WriterImpl}

import org.mockito.MockitoSugar
import org.scalatest.matchers.should.Matchers
import org.scalatest.wordspec.AnyWordSpec

import scala.concurrent.Future

class ProgramTest extends AnyWordSpec with MockitoSugar with Matchers {
  "Program " should {
    "return the mocked succf " in {
      val succf  = Future.successful(scala.collection.immutable.List(new Attribute))
      val bb     = new BoundingBox(41.90178412, 41.8798685, -87.62687021, -87.64884287)
      val writer = mock[WriterImpl[Attribute]]
      when(writer.read(bb)).thenReturn(succf)
    
      val result = writer.read(bb)
    
      verify(writer, times(1)).read(bb)
      result shouldBe succf
    }
  }
}
```

Here's my `build.sbt` in case you need it:

```
libraryDependencies += "org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "3.2.12" % Test
libraryDependencies += "org.scalatestplus" %% "scalacheck-1-16" % "3.2.12.0" % Test
libraryDependencies += "org.scalatestplus" %% "mockito-4-5" % "3.2.12.0" % Test
libraryDependencies += "org.mockito" % "mockito-core" % "4.6.1" % Test
libraryDependencies += "org.mockito" %% "mockito-scala" % "1.17.7" % Test
```